# Normalize values in a multiindex dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, normalize

How do I normalize a multiindex dataframe?

Let's say I have the dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([["a",1,3],["a",2,2],["b",4,4],["b",5,8]], 
                  columns=["name","value1","value2"])
```

how do I calculate the normalized values for each "name"?

I know how to normalize a basic dataframe:

```
d = (d-d.mean(axis=0))/data.std(axis=0, ddof=1)
```

but I'm not able to apply this on each "name" group of my dataframe

SO the result I want is:

```
name, value1, value2
a     -0.5     0.5
a      0.5    -0.5
b     -0.5    -1
b      0.5     1
```

I tried groupby and a multiindex data frame but probably I'm not doing it in the right way

Comment: When you say *'calculate the normalized values for each "name"'*, do you want to normalize ***within each column*** (vertically), not "within a group" => normalize across a single ***row***?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normalizing by group is [one of the examples in the groupby documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation). But it doesn't do exactly what you seem to want here.

```
In [2]: d.groupby('name').transform(lambda x: (x-x.mean())/x.std(ddof=1))
Out[2]: 
     value1    value2
0 -0.707107  0.707107
1  0.707107 -0.707107
2 -0.707107 -0.707107
3  0.707107  0.707107
```

Your desired result suggests that you actually want to normalize the values in each name group with reference to the elements in `value1` and `value2`. For something like that, you can apply a function to each group individually, and reassemble the result.

```
In [3]: def normalize(group):                                                      
    mean = group.values.ravel().mean()
    std = group.values.ravel().std(ddof=1)
    return group.applymap(lambda x: (x - mean)/std)
   ....: 

In [4]: pd.concat([normalize(group) for _, group in d.set_index('name').groupby(level=0)])
Out[4]: 
        value1    value2
name                    
a    -1.224745  1.224745
a     0.000000  0.000000
b    -0.660338 -0.660338
b    -0.132068  1.452744
```

Comment: Apparently `flatten` makes a copy of the array.  `ravel()` works the same, but without the copy.

Comment: Thank you both! sorry I cannot upvote yet due my low reputation! I'm starting to have a better vision on how to work with pandas noW!

Comment: OP wants to normalize within a ***column***, not "within a group" => normalize across a single ***row***.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the result you gave is the correct one?  I'm assuming you want to normalize value1 and value2 separately.  If that's not correct, let me know.

```
#  Easier with `name` as the index.

In [65]: d = d.set_index('name')

In [66]: d
Out[66]: 
      value1  value2
name                
a          1       3
a          2       2
b          4       4
b          5       8

In [68]: means = g.mean()

In [69]: stds = g.std()

In [70]: means
Out[70]: 
      value1  value2
name                
a        1.5     2.5
b        4.5     6.0

In [71]: stds
Out[71]: 
        value1    value2
name                    
a     0.707107  0.707107
b     0.707107  2.828427

In [76]: g.transform(lambda x: (x - means) / stds)
Out[76]: 
        value1    value2
name                    
a    -0.707107  0.707107
a     0.707107 -0.707107
a          NaN       NaN
b          NaN       NaN
b    -0.707107 -0.707107
b     0.707107  0.707107

# Get rid of the nans

In [77]: g.transform(lambda x: (x - means) / stds).dropna()
Out[77]: 
        value1    value2
name                    
a    -0.707107  0.707107
a     0.707107 -0.707107
b    -0.707107 -0.707107
b     0.707107  0.707107
```

Comment: yes sorry you are correct, I normalized it in the wrong way!
Thanks a ton, for future reference I think you forgot 
g = d.groupby("name")